# Chrome adds non breaking space in text copied from PDF and pasted to TinyMCE

Tags: google-chrome, pdf, tinymce

I'm afraid this is highly specific, so please bear with me and read carefully.

### The problem:

Open a PDF file, select and copy some text that contains line breaks and paste it into a TinyMCE textarea in the Google Chrome browser. Then delete any line break and insert a space at the same point: the space that is added is non-breaking even though I used a regular "space bar" key stroke in TinyMCE.

### How do I know there is a non-breaking space?

You can click the "show invisible characters" button on the first row of my TinyMCE implementation (see link below). **Remember that with TinyMCE your must turn that option Off and On again every time you modify the text to see the changes**.

The non-breaking spaces will appear in orange, normal spaces appear normally.

### What I have found so far:

If I delete the character that comes after the line break and then type that character again, I can insert a normal space. The problem seems to be attached to that character.
If I delete the character occuring before the line break, the problem persists, i.e. when I delete the space and type a new space it is still a non breaking space.

Also when I save the text to the MySQL database, and read it again in TinyMCE, the problem still occurs, which reinforces my impression that the "hidden" character is attached to the letter following the line break (there is no saving on the test page of course).

### Replicating it

You could of course try it yourself, but here is my testbed for you: http://www.roseback.com/test/tinymce4.html

I have tested it with many PDF files that we receive from graphic designers, from many products and eras. These PDFs are the files that are used for printing and there is no problem with those files for that use.
I uploaded a **sample file** here: http://www.roseback.com/test/languedoc.pdf. Test with the first paragraph starting with "Ce film exceptionnel".
However I have also tested random PDF files from the web and replicated the problem every time. So if you try with your own files and can't replicate, that might be interesting.

### Environment:

**Web page:** the page is in HTML5, in UTF-8.

On the original page, the page is served via PHP and the textarea content comes from a MySQL 5.1 DB. The DB connection is set to UTF-8 in PHP, the content of the table and of the text field is in utf8_unicode_ci

On the test page there is no content and no saving, so no DB is involved.

**Browser:** Chrome. Does not happen in Firefox or Opera (not tested elsewhere)

**TinyMCE:** version 3 and version 4 (both standard version, not jQuery)

**OS:** on Windows 7 Pro 64 bit and also on Windows XP Pro 32 bit

*I would appreciate any feedback, even simple confirmation / replication of the problem.*

Comment: +1 very well defined question

Comment: Thanks, it took me long enough to write, now get replicating! ;) cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, i think what you observe has something to do with the fact that tinymce inserts non breaking spaces instead of spaces. Tinymce needs to so this in order to avoid that the browser shows more than one space concurrently entered as one single space (this is the default browser behaviour).
You can verify this by inserting more than one space and then have a look at the non-visible characters.

Comment: I agree in general, but in this case there is no space at all between 2 letters and then I type ONE space, which becomes non-breaking in Chrome only. There's no reason for that. Also when I add a space at any other point except where there used to be a line break, the problem DOES NOT occur...